# MFC MDI CMFCPropertyGridProperty adding Array for dropdown list merging MP4 tag data

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-2017, mfc, mdi

I need some guidance on how to add a drop down list from an array of data after the read info from the MP4 Tag data is parsed. The mechanism I'm using is 100% operational, this is a creature feature addition. The MP4 tag I'm working with is Genre using the ID3V1 standard. There are 191 choices. The way my app was inherited, there are 2 columns, property/value and multiple rows. All of that works. The Genre tag was setup willy nilly so you could basically type whatever and it would store it. I want to remove that and have the 191 elements in the array to choose from using the drop down list. Part of the loading process is that it will pull in whatever was in the MP4 file. So, I want the user to be able to leave as is (most likely tagged by something that supports ID3V2), or select from the populated 191 elements in the dropdown list.

The object looks like this information.h:

```
protected:
    CMFCPropertyGridCtrl m_wndProperties;
```

The information.cpp looks like this:

```
void CInformationView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    // create property grid
    VERIFY(m_wndProperties.Create(WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_TABSTOP| WS_BORDER, CRect(0,0,0,0), this, 0));

    // get document
    CMovieDoc *lpkDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID_PTR(lpkDoc);

    // add properties //Information ORDER Loading <<<<< List shortened Stack overflow question
    m_wndProperties.AddProperty(lpkDoc->m_pkArtist);
    m_wndProperties.AddProperty(lpkDoc->m_pkTempo);
    m_wndProperties.AddProperty(lpkDoc->m_pkGenre);

    CView::OnInitialUpdate();
}
```

The way it pulls the data in from mp4.cpp:

```
// Genre
m_pkGenre = new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("Genre"),
    COleVariant(AfxStringFromUtf8(lptTags->genre), VT_BSTR));
```

The pointers in mp4.h:

```
CMFCPropertyGridProperty *m_pkArtist;
CMFCPropertyGridProperty *m_pkTempo;
CMFCPropertyGridProperty *m_pkGenre;
```

Now I know that pull downs in the 2nd column (Values) can be done because other tags have simple TRUE/FALSE that can be selected, so that tells me it should be possible to create the drop down list I'm looking to do. An example of the TRUE/FALSE looks like this:

```
// Compilation
m_pkCompilation = new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("Compilation"),
    COleVariant((!VALID_PTR(lptTags->compilation)) ? (short)0 : (short)*lptTags->compilation, VT_BOOL));
```

I've done arrays in C for things like microcontrollers, but not entirely sure if it is the same in C++. I'm thinking it should look like this:

```
// Initialize Genre Array
const char *genre[4] = { "Rock", "Rap", "Soul", "House" };
```

The questions are:

1. How do I create an the array (or does my example above look correct?) to house fixed strings like "Rock", "Rap", "Soul", etc. etc?
2. How to modify the VALUE row to have the pull down that contains the parsed Genre tag present and then when opened, show the 191 Genre tags where one can be selected to choose from (and ultimately save which is already working).
3. Actual code, not references to the learn.microsoft.com, the few things I've tried crashes when I try to alter the AddProperties I assume because of the lpkDoc pointers being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should not use a plain old C-style array if you do not have a strong reason to. Use a `std::vector` instead. You don't even need to indicate the `[size]`.
   The same goes for `char *`. Use a `CString` or a`std::string` instead.

   ```
   const std::vector<CString> = { L"Rock", L"Rap", L"Soul", L"House" };
   ```

Don't make your life harder than it needs to be.

2.

```
for (size_t i= 0; i < genre.size(); i++)
{
     auto gnr= genre[i];
     lpkDoc->m_pkGenre->AddOption(gnr);
}
```

or even better

```
for (auto it : genre)
{
     lpkDoc->m_pkGenre->AddOption(it);
}
```

Important note: You should not have code about properties in your doc object. You are mixing business logic with user interaction logic. Your code in the future will be a nightmare to maintain.

3. I do not see your `lpkDoc->m_pk` variable init'ed anywhere, and I bet those pointers are pointing to no man's land.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the Vector, I'll give that a go & the AddOption for the looping tag fill. I didn't see where they were initialized either so I did this: CMFCPropertyGridProperty *m_pkAlbum = 0; to all the pointers to start at 0, verified no impact to operation. In terms of the business end.....this was abandoned source code with a reason...I've kept the reason in place and heavily modifying the GUI for better user interaction. I am trying to fix up where I can without impacting operation. Thank you for your help, will report back. Chris

Comment: This works a treat...had to change array to read: const std::vector<CString> genre = { L"Rock", L"Rap", L"Soul", L"House" }; (i.e. missing genre identifier!). Used option #2....loaded right in and worked out of the gate....brilliant! TY! A good learning experience for sure.

Comment: As FYI, option 3 tosses this error: Error C2664 'BOOL CMFCPropertyGridProperty::AddOption(LPCTSTR,BOOL)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const WCHAR' to 'LPCTSTR'  --------- for (*it);

Comment: For 2. remove the `*`. I tought it was a pointer.

Comment: For 1. `CMFCPropertyGridProperty *m_pkAlbum = 0;` that's just idiot and every time you  will access there, you get a crash caused by trying to get data from a null pointer. You need to have that already defined somewhere or create one with `new`.

Comment: Ok, what is the best way to init: CMFCPropertyGridProperty *m_pkAlbum = 0;  I guess I am unclear on the proper way to do this. Can you possibly give an example? Thank you.

Comment: You have the answer in your question.